# Is there a way to add limit in global config model.js ? to limit find results across models in sails.js waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Is there a way to add a limit in global config model.js ? to limit model.find() results across models in sails.js waterline. As I searched the sails docs, dont find any direct config to use.
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-models.

Are there are any hacks or workaround, where I configure it one place and all models find queries get the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't an easy way to change `.find()`'s behavior. However, you could very easily build a custom [`helper`](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers) function, which you can then access through `sails.helpers.mySpecialHelper()`.

So, in this case, you'd pass in the model you want to `.find()`, and your criteria to the helper function, and said helper would return back the results the way you want them found.

Then, inside of your helper, just do something like:

```js
PassedInModel.find(passedInCriteria);
```